# Formatting a number in 1000s shows T instead of K

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

```
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", {
    maximumSignificantDigits: 3,
    notation: "compact",
    compactDisplay: "short",
  }).format(1234),
);
```

this outputs `"1.23T"` and not `"1.23k"` as the short form for the number 1234. Is that right?

Changing the locale to `en-US` outputs `1.23K`. Isn't it supposed to be K for all locales since K means Kilo?

Is there a way to display K for `en-IN` locale?

Comment: I don't know exactly what the rules are for english in India, but it seems plausible that they would use a different abbreviation for one thousand. Maybe T is short for "thousand", or maybe it's got something to do with the Crore and Lakh system. This might be more of a question for a linguist than for a programmer...

Comment: @Abhi did you find any solution apart from using replace?

Comment: @Abhi no, it seems T is correct for Indian locale. I've seen some apps having 1.3T stars on Google Play for 1,300 stars. So I guess T is what it should be.